# PyMongo, fastest way to return and concatenate results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I'm new to mongoDB and was looking for a very fast way to find data and concatenate that data into one array. Right now, I have:

```
search_query = {"index" : {"$lt" : datetime.now() : "$gt" : datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)}
filter_query = {"MyData" : 1, "_id" : 0}
search_result = myCollection.find(search_query,filter_query).sort("index",-1).allow_disk_use(True)
```

The purpose of the above is to find the last 10 minutes of data and return only the `MyData` entries. A cursor is returned, and each cursor elements consists of a dictionary such as `{"MyData" : [15, 0.5,16]}`. I would like to concatenate this into one continuous data batch.

```
all_data = list()
for data in search_result: 
    all_data.extend(data ["MyData"])
```

However, this can be very time consuming to iterate over each element.

I have tried the following as well:

```
all_data = list(search_result)
```

Although it appears to be faster, it is a list of dictionaries `[{"MyData" : [15,12,13]},{"MyData" : [5,6,1]}, ...]`
I would still need to do a comprehension list or loop to properly format the data.

In mongodb, is there a fast way to do the following.

1. Access all cursor elements very fast
2. Concatenate the data in all the cursor elements

I was looking into `aggregation` but wasn't sure.

```
record1 = {"index" : datetime, "MyData" : [10, 11, 12]}
record2 = {"index" : datetime, "MyData" : [13, 14, 15]}
record3 = {"index" : datetime, "MyData" : [16, 17, 18]}
```

Comment: Use the aggregation pipeline, it's designed for transforming data

Comment: Can you add an example of your documents?

Comment: Just added an example, thanks